# Windows 7 RDP Host will not allow local

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vmware

I have a Windows 7 in a VM Host which has RDP enabled - Recently we found we can no longer connect from a Windows server 2008 R2 machine on the same subnet using RDP

Machines on different subnets can connect

The error I get is Source:TermDD ErrorID 56
The Terminal Server security layer detected an error in the protocol stream and has disconnected the client. Client IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

The most recent change was an upgrade of the virtual ESXi hosts from V5 to V5.5 (including BIOS and network drivers) - so that's my current focus however has anyone seen a similar problem with local machines not working and routed machines being able to connect?

IPV6 is enabled on the Windows 7 machine but is not enabled on any client machine however I have tested with IPV6 disabled and there is no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few weeks - I found out the upgrade to VMWare disabled TLS1.0  - there seems to be no need for this as I re-enabled it and VMware still works.  The red-herring was because the person who upgraded Vmware also upgraded the routed clients to support TLS2 - but not the local ones.